# Что делать если низкий ФПС после билда под андроид?

Tags: unity3d

Пробую сделать 2D игру, в компьютере фпс стабильный, но как только я переношу всё на андроид фпс понижается до 30 кадров примерно. Весь интернет обшарил, никакого рабочего способа не нашёл.

1. Я всё пишу в FixedUpdate
2. Пробовал менять FixedTimestep
3. Писал в код:
   Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
   QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;

Мой код движения для игрока:

> transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

Чего ещё я не попробовал?

Comment: Профайлить, профайлить и ещё раз профайлить до полного отлова узких мест. Но, возможно, этим узким местом есть допотопный телефон

Comment: Спасибо, попробую данный вариант

Comment: Возможно проблема не только в этой строчке, вам поможет только работа в профайле

Comment: Я зря не сказал какая игра, жанр - гиперказуалка. Я только создал проект, и по быстрому добавил кружок, кнопку и написал скрипт движения, после чего забилдил на андроид. По сути ничего не сделал, что здесь может работать неправильно?